# How to transform translateX an element until the end of its content hits the right side of the parent element using CSS?

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-transforms

Is it possible with CSS to set `transform: translateX()` in a way that:

> … the content moves to the left until the end of the content reaches the right side of the parent container?

To illustrate the issue:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.wrapper.moved {
  transform: translateX(-95px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="wrapper">Start of some content with an eventual end …</span>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span class="wrapper moved">Start of some content with an eventual end …</span>
</div>
```

Now, here I moved the content explicitly. But in real life I don't know how long the content is. Of course using something like `-100%` is way to far.

So, is there a way – without calculating the width of the overflow using JavaScript – to move the content until it hits the right side of the container?

Comment: No...a transform is entirely visual. The element does not actually move. CSS can't detect placement or position only style elements based on a selector. You **do** need JS.

Comment: ...but I'm curious as to the use-case for this. Seems to me there would be other methods of moving the element.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, @Paulie_D. That's what I figured. The use case is the title of an audio track. Kinda like in Spotify. If the title is too long it scrolls until it reaches the the right side and then scrolls back.

Answer (score 2):

If the width of the container is known like in your example you can do this using `calc()` but you have to make the inner element `inline-block`

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width:100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.wrapper.moved {
  transform: translateX(calc(200px - 100%));
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="wrapper">Start of some content with an eventual end …</span>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span class="wrapper moved">Start of some content with an eventual end …</span>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span class="wrapper moved">Start of some content with an eventual end content with an eventual end …</span>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span class="wrapper moved">Start of some content</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. This is helpful, if the width is fixed. Unfortunately it's a responsive layout an the width of the element can vary.